# dompdf form submit didn't send data codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

i am trying to create an PDF using Dompdf, in my program i have model query with a dynamic parameter based on the input in the form, but when i click on my button to send the value from the select button to the controller, the data not been send properly, any idea why? below are my code

```
<form class="form" method="get" action="<?=site_url()?>/laporan/pdfdownload" id="myID" name="myName">
    <select id="sel1" class="form-control">
         <option disabled selected="selected">Pilih</option>
                  <?php foreach ($kerja as $rows){?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $rows->id_project?>"><?php echo $rows->id_project.' - '.$rows->nama_project ?></option>
                  <?php }?>
    </select>
    <select id="sel2" class="form-control">
         <option disabled selected="selected">Pilih</option>
                  <?php foreach ($item as $rows){?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $rows->id_project?>"><?php echo $rows->id_project.' - '.$rows->nama_project ?></option>
                  <?php }?>
    </select>
   <button id="filter_button" style="margin-top: 26px;margin-left: 28px;width: auto" name="filter_button" type="submit" class="form btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbspSearch</button>
</form>
```

and here is my controller

```
public function pdfdownload(){
                                      //If i click submit then all of the post didnt get sended
    $one = $this->input->post('sel1');//no value at all, anyone know why?
    $two = $this->input->post('sel2');//no value at all, anyone know why?

    $data['real'] = $this->report_m($one,$two)->row();

    htmlcontent = $this->load->view('laporan/download/laporan3.php',$data,true);
    include(APPPATH."third_party/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
    // require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    $dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
    $dompdf->load_html($htmlcontent);
    $dompdf->set_paper("f4");
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("cobadlu.pdf",array("Attachment" => false));
    exit(0);
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML form, you need to use name attribute, and not only ID :

```
<select id="sel2" name="sel2" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a mistake in your form:

```
<form class="form" method="get" action="<?=site_url()?>/laporan/pdfdownload" id="myID" name="myName">
```

You given the **method='get'** here, please change it to **'post'**.

Second you are not include the **'name'** attribute to the input type so after submit no data will send. So add the name attribute like that:

```
<select id="sel1" name="sel1" class="form-control">
<select id="sel2" name="sel2" class="form-control">
```